# Displaying Sudoku solution, using Grid-Layout and JLabels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, jlabel

I am working on a GUI for my Sudoku Solver, using a Grid-Layout and JLabels to display the board. I am able to successfully display the initial board, but when I click my "Solve" Button, I am unsure of how to re-draw the board with the solution.

This is my draw method that is called in the constructor and succesfully draws the initial values onto the board.

```
  public void drawGame(){
    String s = "";
    for(int z = 0; z < ninePuzzle.length; z++){
        int row, col;
        if((z%dimension) > 0){
            row = z / dimension;
            col = z % dimension;
            board[row][col] = ninePuzzle[z];
        }
        else{
            row = z / dimension;
            col = 0;
            board[row][col] = ninePuzzle[z];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){

        for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++){
            if(board[i][j] == -1){

                gamePanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
            }
            else{
                s = "";
                s = "" + board[i][j];
                gamePanel.add(new JLabel(s));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the Solve JButton is clicked I though that "re-using" this part of the drawGame() method would work. What am I doing wrong here?

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if("solve".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
        if (solvePuzzle(board)) {
            String s = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                    if (board[i][j] == -1) {

                        gamePanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
                    } else {
                        s = "";
                        s = "" + board[i][j];
                        gamePanel.add(new JLabel(s));
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        else {

        }
    }       
}
```

Note: I am leaving the else empty for now, the initial values for this particular sudoku array[][] always has a correct soln.

Comment: Not really sure what you are doing, but I wonder why you would add new components to the frame when you click on a "Solve" button? Why don't you just updated the text on the labels already displayed on the screen?

Comment: would I use .setText for that? @camickr

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are adding new labels when you click on button, you should better define an global 9x9 JLabel matrix, then pass it to drawGame and add them to panel.
Now on button click you just want to update their value using nameOfMatrix[i][j].setText("Your text");

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED CODE**

Used a JLabel[][] in the drawGame method:

```
public void drawGame(){
    String s = "";
    for(int z = 0; z < ninePuzzle.length; z++){
        int row, col;
        if((z%dimension) > 0){
            row = z / dimension;
            col = z % dimension;
            board[row][col] = ninePuzzle[z];
        }
        else{
            row = z / dimension;
            col = 0;
            board[row][col] = ninePuzzle[z];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){

        for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++){
            if(board[i][j] == -1){
                game[i][j] = new JLabel(" ");
                gamePanel.add(game[i][j]);
            }
            else{
                s = "";
                s = "" + board[i][j];
                game[i][j] = new JLabel(s);
                gamePanel.add(game[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the actionPerformed code for when the "Solve" button is clicked.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if("solve".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
        if (solvePuzzle(board)) {

            String s = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                    s = "" + board[i][j];

                    game[i][j].setText(s);

                }
            }
        }

    }
    if("clear".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
        for(int z = 0; z < ninePuzzle.length; z++){
            int row, col;
            if((z%dimension) > 0){
                row = z / dimension;
                col = z % dimension;
                board[row][col] = ninePuzzle[z];
            }
            else{
                row = z / dimension;
                col = 0;
                board[row][col] = ninePuzzle[z];
            }
        }
        String s = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){

            for(int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++){
                if(board[i][j] == -1){
                    game[i][j].setText(" ");

                }
                else{
                    s = "";
                    s = "" + board[i][j];
                    game[i][j].setText(s);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```